# How do you access @font-face in the DOM (via Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, font-face

Hi I'm looking to access @font-face with Javascript.  I assume it's somewhere in the DOM but where?

I want to do this for @font-face feature detection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a link to [this article](http://paulirish.com/2009/font-face-feature-detection/) inside the [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) library.

It doesn't look like you can query the DOM (unless both these methods are giving it the run around just for showmanship).

Answer (score 0):

You mean [`CSSFontFaceRule`](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/css/CSSFontFaceRule.html)?

For detection you can use [this](http://github.com/Mouvedia/lack-of-font-face-support-detection).